# Mongoid has many nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm developing Rails app in which I receive data from outside and store it in MongoDB, I'm using Mongoid as ODM.

The task is pretty simple: I have `Topic` model which should have and belongs to many `Rubrics`, the main problem here is that rubrics should be nested (one level though).

The first solution I came upon was:

```
models/rubric.rb

class Rubric
  include Mongoid::Document

  recursively_embeds_many
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

models/topic.rb

class Topic
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :rubrics
end
```

**Pros**

Rubrics stored in their own collection, so it's easy to update their attributes (suppose I need to edit rubric's title).

**Cons**

Mongoid won't let me to access nested rubrics from topics, that is: topic.rubrics returns all rubrics **but** nested, which is basically right – mongoid shouldn't allow access to embeded documents from outside.

Not working.

Second solution:

```
models/rubric.rb

class Rubric
  include Mongoid::Document

  recursively_embeds_many
  embeded_in :topic
end

models/topic.rb

class Topic
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :rubrics
end
```

**Pros**

Mongo way? To store all collection-associated data inside that collection.

**Cons**

Rubrics are not completely separate collection, if I need to change rubric I have **to loop through all topics** changing rubric.

Mongoid won't let me to access nested rubrics from topics, that is: topic.rubrics returns all rubrics **but** nested, which is basically right – mongoid shouldn't allow access to embeded documents from outside.

Not very DRY solution as rubrics will be duplicated among topics.

Not working.

Third solution:

```
models/rubric.rb

class Rubric
  include Mongoid::Document

  recursively_embeds_many
  embeded_in :topic
end

models/subrubric.rb

class Subrubric
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :rubric
  belongs_to :topic
end

models/topic.rb

class Topic
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :rubrics
  has_many :subrubrics
end
```

**Pros**

The only advantage is that this solution is the only one which actually works, but:

**Cons**

This approach only works if rubric is only nested once (which is ok for this project). But I want to have universal solution which would work with any level of nesting.

Comment: I don't get why you want to embed `rubrics` into `topics`. If you are making a forum, imo it should respect this schema: `forum > rubrics > topics`, where `topics` can belong to one `Rubric` at a time.

Comment: @jigz. I don't want to, actually. The problem is to have topic has_many rubrics, whereas rubrics are nested.

Comment: Having the `_id` of an embeded document is 'useless' if you don't have `_ids` of all its parents.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320156/mongoid-find-embedded-document/20688850#20688850